# Change Button text and disable it during post back

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a button inside an `update panel`.

I want it so when user clicks the button, a `Please Wait...` text shows as button text, and the button is disabled until post back completes. I've written this code:

```
$('#Button2').on("click", function (e) {
                $("#Button2").val("Please Wait");
                $('#Button2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

The problem is when the button is being disabled, its event is not raised on server side. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should call server event after disabling button.for this you should using `ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(bt1, null)`

please see this link :[Disable button in update panel on async postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828143/disable-button-in-update-panel-on-async-postback)

Answer (score 4):

Are you using jQuery.ajax function to trigger the server call? If so, then do the button text changes and disable in "beforeSend" key.

```
$.ajax({
    .....
    beforeSend: function(){
     $("#Button2").val("Please Wait");
     $('#Button2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    .....
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#Button2').on("click", function (e) {
                $("#Button2").text("Please Wait");
                $('#Button2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
               //your ajax function here
     $.ajax({
            url:'your url',
            data : ({/*data to send***/  }),
            method : 'POST',

            success: function(msg){
                 $('#Button2').removeAttr('disabled');
           }
    });
             //end ajax


});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .attr and .html functions in jQuery.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $(this).html('Saving...'); //this changes the html to Saving...
    $(this).attr('disabled', true); //this will disable the button onclick
});
```

Here's a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stan255/cpLqK/1/

Hope this helps.

- Stanley

Answer (score 0):

In your onClick function try making the ajax call first and then disabling the button after it. Since it is an asynchronous call the next line of script should disable the button while the call is made. The in your callback after the call is made you can re enable your button.