# Best way to fight user's, unwanted, second click in web app

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, user-interface, webforms

Using asp.net

I have some users, which are a bit impatient. I have some ajax buttons, which sometimes receive a second click as the user thinks he's waited long enough.... I have some routines round tripping to a quickbooks SDK service, so at times, users can wait for maybe 15-20 seconds (while my ajax icon spins..)

I am currently combating this, by setting a session variable on the first click, and then on any consecutive clicks, I check the time difference from the last click. If less than a certain threshold, I exit that button click sub. On every successful click, on sub exit, I clear this session variable.

I there a better way to do this? I would almost think that this is a common issue? Are there any built in routines to handle this kind of thing, that I may have missed?

Comment: Why dont you setup a `timeout` for your ajax call and disable the button once it is clicked

Comment: I recently thought about disabling... but was/am looking for ideas on what other guys are using... I may change it to disable, as its slightly less code... but was curious as to if there is something already "built in" somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should follow Murali's advice and just disable the button client-side until either the `Ajax` call returns (success or error) or times out. By disabling it, you are explicitly telling the user "this button is not available to you right now".

- This way you can avoid ambiguity for the user - regarding your assumption that the user is "impatient" - are you sure about this? For all we know it could be that they assume that because the button did *not* disable, something went wrong and so they'd better try again.
- Perhaps your Ajax spinner indicator isn't obvious enough by itself - it's not uncommon for a hanging/crashing app to leave its "wait a minute" spinner visible so the user might well feel that the page has just given up the ghost on them. Visibly disabling the button solves this problem.

Update: Given that this is webforms, the best solution is probably to check the [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.isInAsyncPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383989.aspx) property on the client

Comment: My one concern with disable, was to keep state of the control (Will the control always be kept? Aren't they re-created on postback?). I was worried that on postback, the initial disabled control, would now be missing, as the page controls was rebuilt? This comment, based on my experience with user controls being destroyed and rebuilt, and their event wireup going missing.

Comment: But aren't these ajax buttons - you're not doing a page load in this case, just making an async background call? i.e the disabling os only on the client side. If you re-load the page, the control re-rendered.

Comment: Please excuse my lack of in-depth Ajax knowledge... :-) , I am/was not aware that disabling the button, will disable it client side? This is a normal image button, inside an ajax updatpanel. I was under the impression that it will be disabled, in code, server side...? (physically)

Comment: Ah, I did not realise you were using webforms (I have updated and added tag). Yes a partial postback will occur in this case, but you should still be able to intercept the click client-side first, and disable the button, see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828143/disable-button-in-update-panel-on-async-postback or this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383989.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do it client side in the onlick event. Write something similar to your server side code in javascript that sets the last click time on the button itself (new property) and check it in subsequent clicks. That way you avoid a trip to the server.