# how to show Progress text on button with jquery while Page Do Oparation In Back ground

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i just want to display Progress.. text on asp.net button control while page do some operation in back ground. here i found code with it but i try to pass this function to button. but it's not displaying Progress.. text while page do back ground process.

here is jquery code progress.js:

```
function ClientSideClick(myButton) {
            // Client side validation
            if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
                if (Page_ClientValidate() == false)
                { return false; }
            }

            //make sure the button is not of type "submit" but "button"
            if (myButton.getAttribute('type') == 'button') {
                // diable the button
                myButton.disabled = true;
                myButton.className = "button";
                myButton.value = "Process..";
            }
            return true;
        }
```

and here is my button :

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_Login" runat="server" Text="Login" CssClass="btn-active" 
onclick="btn_Login_Click" ValidationGroup="Login" 
onclientclick="ClientSideClick(this)" UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>
```

can i applied wrong method calling with onclientclick.

**------------------------------Updated---------------------------**

this is button click event :

```
 protected void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
            {
                var query = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals(txt_username.Text.Trim()) && u.password.Equals(txt_password.Text.Trim())).Select(u => new
                            {
                                IsVerified = u.IsVerified,
                                IsActive = u.IsActive,
                                status_id = u.status_id,
                                group_id = u.group_id,
                                Type_Name = db.Types.Where(t => t.Id.Equals(u.type_id)).Select(t => t.type_name).FirstOrDefault()
                            }).ToList();
                if (query.Count() != 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in query)
                    {
                        if (item.IsActive == true && item.IsVerified == true)
                        {
                            if (chk_remember.Checked)
                            {
                                if (item.Type_Name == "Admin")
                                {
                                    Response.Cookies["UName"].Value = txt_username.Text.Trim();
                                    Response.Cookies["PWD"].Value = txt_password.Text.Trim();
                                    Response.Cookies["UName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                                    Response.Cookies["PWD"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                                    Session["Username"] = txt_username.Text.Trim();
                                    Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Admin_Landing_Page.aspx");
                                    break;
                                }
                                else if (item.Type_Name == "User")
                                {
                                    Response.Cookies["UName"].Value = txt_username.Text.Trim();
                                    Response.Cookies["PWD"].Value = txt_password.Text.Trim();
                                    Response.Cookies["UName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                                    Response.Cookies["PWD"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                                    Session["Username"] = txt_username.Text.Trim();
                                    Session["status_id"] = item.status_id.ToString();
                                    if (item.group_id != null)
                                    {
                                        Session["group_id"] = item.group_id.ToString();
                                    }
                                    Response.Redirect("~/EndUser/User_Landing_Page.aspx");
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Response.Cookies["UName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
                                Response.Cookies["PWD"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
                                if (item.Type_Name == "Admin")
                                {
                                    Session["Username"] = txt_username.Text.Trim();
                                    Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Admin_Landing_Page.aspx");
                                    break;
                                }
                                else if (item.Type_Name == "User")
                                {
                                    Session["Username"] = txt_username.Text.Trim();
                                    Session["status_id"] = item.status_id.ToString();
                                    if (item.group_id != null)
                                    {
                                        Session["group_id"] = item.group_id.ToString();
                                    }
                                    Response.Redirect("~/EndUser/User_Landing_Page.aspx");
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (item.IsActive == false && item.IsVerified == true)
                        {
                            ltr_errormessage.Text = "<span style='color:red'>Authentication failed contact admin.</span>";
                        }
                        else if (item.IsActive == true && item.IsVerified == false)
                        {
                            ltr_errormessage.Text = "<span style='color:red'>Account not verified.</span>";
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ltr_errormessage.Text = "<span style='color:red'>Invalid username or password</span>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok i found article that same explain that i want [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43093/Submit-Once-with-an-ASP-NET-Button-Server-Control)

Comment: You can toggle text of button while some operation is going on in background

Comment: Have you considered using ajax? You can disable the button and change the text inside the function and before the ajax call. Then on success re-enable the button.

Comment: please share ur technique with code.

Comment: like nick said above, use ajax. easiest will be: Wrap the button with `<asp:UpdatePanel><ContentTemplate>...</ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>`, then re-enable the button and it's text (_Login_) in the server side (i.e. in `btn_Login_Click` method).

Comment: Can u make code with this update panel when User Clicks On Button then at Page Back Process update panel change my Button cssClass and text. if result may nagative (no login found) then it back to normal nature. Here i eliminate Page Post back and show diff look with Button to show page doing operation.

Comment: Here for ur help i include my Login button code.

Comment: here i found nice [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828143/disable-button-in-update-panel-on-async-postback).