# Changing Button Text and Enable/Disable it

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a login form, where I need to change the text of login button to PleaseWait… and disable it and once the authentication is verified it will redirect to another page or else it will change back the button text to Login and enable the button.

I tried this with UpdatePanel, but it changes the text only after the whole code is executed inside the button click event.

ASPX code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button Text="Change" runat="server" ID="BtnChangeText" OnClick="BtnChangeText_Click" />
</ContentTemplate>          
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C# code:

```
protected void BtnChangeText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BtnChangeText.Text = "Loading...";
        BtnChangeText.Enabled = false;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
```

I also tried using JavaScript, here I’m able to disable and enable the button, but unable to change the text of the button.

ASPX code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sc" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<script type="text/javascript">
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
                 function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                     document.getElementById('BtnChangeText').innerText = "Processing...";
                     args.get_postBackElement().disabled = true;
                 }
</script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpnlSubmit" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="BtnChangeText" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="BtnChangeText_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C# code:

```
protected void BtnChangeText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        BtnChangeText.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Now I’ll be grateful if anyone can help me with changing the text of button.

Comment: Can you please check if render button has the same Id which you have created in aspx page, look in the rendered html

Comment: everywhere the id is same: BtnChangeText

Comment: possible dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828143/disable-button-in-update-panel-on-async-postback

Comment: I'm able to disable/enable, but unable to change the text on the button through the JavaScript in aspx code

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax to make an asynchronous call :

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/769238/Call-Server-Side-Code-using-ASP-NET-AJAX-and-jQuer

Comment: Hi Glitch, Thanks for replying. I just need to change the text on the button using JavaScript in aspx file. Rest of things are working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked

```
args.get_postBackElement().value = "Please wait...";
```